# xpath multiple condition and return root

Tags: xpath, conditional-statements, exist-db

Is it possible to do a 'and' condition in xpath like

```
//foo/bar/test[@val='hello'] and //foo/bar/new[@val='world']
```

This condition returns true for some reason and not any results. I've tried `|` but I don't need an `or` statement.

The results should return all the elements from //foo (where the conditions match) - I need the root element because I'll be pulling data out from different elements.

I'm using xpath to query an exist-db database

I need to put `//foo[(position()> 3) and (position() < 6)]` in there also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the `foo` elements, start the `[]` just after `foo`:

```
//foo[bar/test/@val='hello' and bar/new/@val='world']
```

If you want the children of `foo`, put the brackets there:

```
//foo/bar[test/@val='hello' and new/@val="world"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this returns the entire root document.

Comment: @user9418: Which of the expressions? How does your document look like?

Comment: Yes! sorry. I had a syntax error in the second one. It was returning zero results as a result. thank you very much for your help.